# Warning message at tails shutdown, is this normal?

Tags: anonymity, tails

When I shutdown Tails it says everything is completed except there's a big warning next to "tails using make-file like concurrent boot at level 0" this has got me sort of worried that I may have downloaded a modified version or something.

I verified the iso using kleopatra but I never went through the any more advanced steps (like web of trust), is this message something normal and not worth worrying about? Or is this a minor safety issue? Have downloaded a forged version of tails? Is this potentially dangerous?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely a normal message and not worth worrying about. Tails aim to shutdown fast, and takes a few shortcuts. Although without the exact message, it's hard to give a definite answer.